# How to populate an ArrayList with ComboBox data in Java

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, combobox

I am trying to figure out why I keep getting an error that says non-static variable destinationList can not be referred to from a static context. I know how the program is supposed to work so I dont need help with that. I was thinking I would be able to just put the items in an ArrayList but that did not work. Any help would be appreciated:)

```
 public static void updateTextFile()
      {


          try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(DESTINATIONS_FILE, true)))
          {

              writer.println(destinationList.getItems());


          }

               catch (IOException ioe)
          {
              System.out.println("Error when attempting to update file");
          }





      }
```

Comment: Your question is is not related to the code I see, file writing, code? You want to take items from a combo box and place them into an ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `static` keyword from your method `updateTextFile()`. Or, if you'd like to keep it static, make `destinationList` itself `static`.

Comment: For some reason I didn't even think of doing that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error pretty much says it all. I am guessing that destinationList is not static? try passing the list into the method as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question. In order to get an ArrayList from a Java8 ComboBox, is quite strait forward API wise [ComboBox API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html)
`getItems();`returns an Obersvable list already. 
[ObservableList API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html)

Simply just either copy the list or use the one provided which any changes to would effect the underlying list. If you want to copy the list, you will need to read about shallow and deep copies and how to. Guides all over the internet for that one.

You can read and write list with the [Java 7 NIO API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

```
Files.write(Path path, Iterable<? extends CharSequence> lines, Charset cs, OpenOption... options)
```

Lucky for you Observable list is iterable!